# does body-parser's urlencode prevent xss?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Why should we use `require('body-parser').urlencode` in my node.js or express app? Does it prevent XSS? Im using it in my app and I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will only handle the decoding. Have a look at [lusca](https://github.com/krakenjs/lusca) and [npm modules about "xss"](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xss) for other candidates.